# Remove XML section from a file on a mac

Tags: xml, bash, command-line-interface

I have a file xml file with the below structure on mac

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://test.com/data">
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>View</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>Edit</name>
    </userPermissions>  
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>Delete</name>
    </userPermissions>  
</Profile>
```

I would like to have a bash/cli script to remove the below section from it.

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>Delete</name>
</userPermissions>
```

How can I do this with sed/awk/xmlstarlet ?

I tried the below. Don't get an error but it does not do the job either.

```
sed -i '' 's#</userPermissions><userPermissions><enabled>true</enabled><name>Delete</name></userPermissions>#</userPermissions>#' FileName.Profile

sed -i '' 's/<\/userPermissions><userPermissions><enabled>true<\/enabled><name>Delete<\/name><\/userPermissions>/<\/userPermissions>/' FileName.Profile
```

tried below with XMLSTARLET as well but no luck

```
XMLStarlet ed --ps -d "/Profile/userPermissions[name='Delete'] FileName.profile"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: sed -i 's/<\/userPermissions><userPermissions><enabled>true<\/enabled><name>Delete<\/name><\/userPermissions>/<\/userPermissions>/' FileName.Profile .. also tried this ... error I get is sed: 1: "FileName.Profile": invalid command code F

Comment: sed/awk/grep is not 100% safe for your requirement. A valid xml file can have different formats, i.e. one line, 3 lines, with/out indent...

Comment: @Kent What would be a preferred option to achieve this ? Ultimately I need to add a script to my CI/CD jobs.

Comment: A tool that can parse XML such as [XmlStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) would make sense.

Comment: @Branjamin I can work with that and have tried XMLstarlet already. But Can't get it to successfully work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) you can execute the following command:

```
xml ed -L -N d="http://test.com/data" -d "d:Profile/d:userPermissions[child::d:name[.='Delete']]" FileName.profile
```

<sub>**Note:** You *may* need to replace the initial `xml` part of the command above with `xmlstarlet`</sub>

**Explanation:**

1. Your source xml includes a [Namespace](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/04/04/trxml/), (i.e. the `xmlns="http://test.com/data"` declaration in the document element's start-tag), so you'll need to utilize XMLStarlet's `-N` option to predefine it when [editing xml documents](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139594320) using the `ed` command.

   As you can see in the command (above) the part that reads;

   ```
   -N d="http://test.com/data"
   ```

   predefines the Namespace using the name `d`.
2. The part that reads:

   ```
   "d:Profile/d:userPermissions[child::d:name[.='Delete']]"
   ```

   defines the [Xpath](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) expression to address the part(s) of the XML document that we're interested in - in this scenario it addresses the element(s) that we want to delete.

   As you can see each reference to an element node is prefixed with `d:`

   Essentially, this *xpath* expression; matches any element nodes named `userPermissions` (belonging to the Namespace; `http://test.com/data`) only if they have a child element node named `name` whose text node equals the word; `"Delete"`.
3. The `-d` option/flag is used to delete what the Xpath expression matches.
4. The `-L` option/flag edits the file inplace. *You may want to initially remove the this option/flag for test purposes*.

**Result**

Given your source XML executing the command (above) will produce the following in the file named `FileName.Profile`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://test.com/data">
  <userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>View</name>
  </userPermissions>
  <userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>Edit</name>
  </userPermissions>
</Profile>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. Appreciate the detail explanation as well for XMLStarlet

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this is how you would use github.com/mikefarah/yq:

```bash
yq -p=xml -o=xml 'del(.Profile.userPermissions[] | select(.name=="Delete"))' Filename.profile
```

Explanation:

- del(....) will delete all matching nodes
- inside del, we find all the userPermissions that have name == "Delete"

The flags:

- `-p=xml` tells yq to parse xml
- `-o=xml` tells yq to output xml

Disclaimer: I wrote yq